# Unable to create embedded h2 database

Tags: java, database, maven, h2

I am using the web console of H2 Version 1.4.198 (2019-02-22)
 to create a embedded database. But I am getting the following error saying "unable to find the database". I want to create the database not open an existing one. I using ubuntu 18.04 and have given execute permisison to h2.jar and h2.sh.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error with the latest ([1.4.198](http://www.h2database.com/h2-2019-02-22.zip)) version.  It works for me with the stable version - 1[.4.197](http://www.h2database.com/h2-2018-03-18.zip).  @sagar-bahadur-tamang can you check your version and try suitably?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work with the latest version. But works with the stable version.

Answer (score 1):

In application.properties or yaml file check spring.datasource.url remove the flag IFEXISTS=TRUE;.

If the flag is set to true, the connection is only established if the database exists. For reference of the flag see http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists

The application properties file should look like as below

**application.properties**

```
h2.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
h2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;FILE_LOCK=NO
h2.datasource.username=sa
h2.datasource.password=

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console/
```

It looks like as below (Test Connection is successful)

[image]

Comment: I am trying to create the embedded using the web console of h2.